# My checkbox value is not getting unchecked on click while retrieving data from service using API and ngModel

Tags: angular, checkbox, service, ngmodel

This is my code..
On edit page, i'm retrieving data from service using ngModel.
My sql table has four columns: Rulename, Delaer_Id, Type and Status.
i'm trying to validate form and update record using api service and the code is as follows. i don't want validation for status checkbox.
I only want to change status checkbox value to "N" by unchecking the checkbox.
On clicking the checkbox value N is reflected in console.
But, checkbox is not getting unchecked. it is remaining checked only.
I want it to be toggled onclickk just like it's value (checked if "Y" and unchecked if "N").

HTML FILE

```
 <form [formGroup]="addTermForm">
             
                       <div class="col-sm-12">  
                        <label style="padding-left: 6px;">Status:</label>
                        <span style="padding-left: 10px;"></span>  
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="Status"
           (change)="statusValueChange($event)" style="margin-left: 10px;" [(ngModel)]="termDetails.Status"
          [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && addTermForm.get('Status').errors}">                        
                    

                     </div>
                          
                      
         </form>
```

TS FILE

```
 
   statusValueChange($event: any) {
    this.addTermForm.controls['Status'].setValue($event.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N');
    console.log('form values:', this.addTermForm.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the below attributes from your checkbox and it will work.

```
formControlName="Status"
[(ngModel)]="termDetails.Status"
```

As you are updating the form Values manually you don't need this.

To show the check/uncheck based on value while editing. you can do below this.

```
 [checked]="myForm.get('Status').value == 'Y'"
```

use the checked attribute and when you recevied the data on editing update the field value like below.

```
this.myForm.get("Status").setValue("Y");
```

Comment: If i remove ngmodel, it will work. But, my page is edit the record page. Suppose if i have a record with rulename: xyz, status as y. On clicking edit record, as per my code using [(ngModek)] it will show the existed values that is xyz and status checkbox checked as the value is y.  Now, as you said if i remove [( ngModel)] = "termDetails.status", wgen i edit record checkbox will be empty as we are not binding data. I want the data to be bound as well as checkmark to be toggled.

Comment: Ok. This works for the record which has the status as Y. What about the record that has the status as N ? For the above code it's showing the checkbox checked for N also..example i have a record rulename: abc and status N. On editing the checkbox should be empty value right? Can we do that dynamic? Can you please elaborate the explanation please

Comment: Or is there any other ways to send checkbox value as Y if checked and N if the checkbox is unchecked. ? Above code i used  (change)="statusValueChange($event)". Can you please tell the alternative for this instead?

Comment: Actually, the same checkbox code is working well for add screen. That is my add new record page. But getting issue while retrieving and updating.

Comment: For value  'N' checkbox will be unchecked. check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-form-p9t3e). The problem is with your data model, why you are storing value as Y and N?

Comment: I was instructed to save the values as Y and N only in database for checkbox on checked and unchanged.

Comment: Ok, Above solution will work in case of editing also, please check the link.

Comment: This is working for add new record page. For edit page, when i use the same. I'm not able to get its value that is checkbox remaining unchecked even when i edit a record  with status Y.

Comment: please share the link codesandbox or stackblitz.